# django datetimefield migration validation error

Tags: django, datetime, migration, field, validationerror

I haven't been able to figure out how to do what I want (not have to set datetime upon creation of object) and get around this error.

Django 1.11, Python 3.6. I am currently in the process of upgrading from Django 1.8.

Problem occurs when I run python manage.py migrate

```
  File "C:\Dev\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields
  \__init__.py", line 1423, in to_python
  params={'value': value},
  django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["Value '' has an invalid date 
  format. Must be in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ]."]
```

My previous models.py (In Django 1.8)

```
    timeToServe = models.DateTimeField(default='', null=True, blank=True,
                                   verbose_name=get_lang(None, 'time_to_serve'))
```

My current models.py (In Django 1.11)

```
timeToServe = models.DateTimeField(default=None,
    null=True, blank=True,
    auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False,
    verbose_name=get_lang(None, 'time_to_serve'))
```

My previous migration file (In Django 1.8)

```
('timeToServe', models.DateTimeField(default='', blank=True, verbose_name='Serveringstid', null=True)),
```

My current migration (0021_auto_xxxx.py) (In Django 1.11)

```
    operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='booking',
        name='timeToServe',
        field=models.DateTimeField(
            default=None, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='time'),
    ),
```

Comment: Was the previous version of this models field a `CharField`, perhaps?

Comment: Field has not previously been a CharField.

Comment: is there any objects exist for `timeToServe` model?

Comment: in the migration file, we can actually see `migrations.AlterField` that means the field has some previous arguments, so what were they?

Comment: Yes, there are objects in the database.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an automatic solution to this. What I did to get around this problem was to:

1. Check what changes in the created migration file actually would result in database changes. In my case there were some and I managed to edit the migration file to reflect those changes and remove all other changes in the migration file. I was then left with changes that Django wanted to do but would not change the database.
2. In my next step I uninstalled the migrations. Note the fake flag.

   python manage.py migrate --fake myAppName zero
3. I deleted all my current migration files and there respective .pyc-file
4. Created new migration files

   Python manage.py makemigrations
5. I installed the new migration file. Note the fake flag.

   python manage.py migrate --fake-initial

To check status of your migrations you can run

- python manage.py showmigrations